# Family Group Sheet with tabularray - suggestions for improvements welcome

Tags: line-breaking, tabularray, genealogy

With the imminent birth of my first grandson, I am trying to record two generations of family history research (mine, and my Father's), by writing a book in latex. There are hundreds of names, going back about 9 generations. Using Family Group Sheets is a concise way of presenting a whole family - parents with children. There are many examples on the internet, as pdfs, MS Word, and Excel documents, but NONE in latex.

Before anyone asks, I have found the genealogytree package (https://ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree), and intend to use it, but it does not produce Family Group Sheets.

I haven't used latex before, so have a lot to learn. It seems that the tabularray package is the way to go. Many thanks to Jianrui Lyu for creating it, as well as to those who have asked questions, which has enabled him to provide answers useful for others.

This is my first post, so I may have made some error somewhere in it. Have I put it in the right place? Should it have gone somewhere else?

I note that someone else has asked a question about Family Groups Sheets in Latex, but without a satisfactory answer. I therefore set about creating my own. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Family Group Sheet}
        \begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth,hspan=minimal,
                colspec={
                |X[c,m,0.3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,0.9cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |}}
            
            \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{c}\normalsize \textbf{Husband} & 1-2 & \SetCell[c=3]{l} name & 1-4 & 1-5 & \normalsize \textbf{Wife} & \SetCell[c=3]{l} name &x&x \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Birth} &x& date &  \textbf{Place} & where & \textbf{Birth} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Military}  &x& \SetCell[c=3]{} what &x&&  \textbf{Marr.} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Death} & x & date &  \textbf{Place} & where &  \textbf{Death} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Burial} & x & date &  \textbf{Place} & where &  \textbf{Burial} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Father} & x & date &  \textbf{Mother} & where &  \textbf{Father} & date &  \textbf{Mother} & where \\ \hline
             \hline
            \SetCell[c=5]{h,l}\SetRow{12ex}\normalsize \textbf{Notes} \footnotesize {\\Write here,  } & 7-2 & 7-3 & 7-4 & 7-5 &  \SetCell[c=4]{h,l} \normalsize \textbf{Notes} \footnotesize {\\Here} & 7-7 & 7-8 & 7-9 \\ \hline
%DO NOT EDIT NEXT LINE          
            \SetCell[c=3]{c}\textbf{Children} & 8-2 & 8-3 & \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Birth} & 8-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Marriage} & 8-7 & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Death and Burial} & 8-9 \\ \hline% DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE
            1 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            2 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            3 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            4 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            6 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            7 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            8 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            9 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            10 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=9]{l}\textbf{Additional Notes}\footnotesize {\\Write here}  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
            \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Family Group Sheet]

There is no copyright on this code, so if anyone else finds it useful, you are welcome. If anyone improves it, please let me know.

I could not get the New Interface for the table definition to work - most likely because I did not understand the syntax, or put in not enough braces. It is also possible that the openSUSE Tumbleweed package I am using is not up to date. hspan=minimal is necessary, in order to get the Notes spanned cells to allow text wrap, and expand the row height. Without that, there is column stretch, and the right hand side of the table goes off the paper.

Note also the use of braces to surround the text in the Note cells. The line break symbol \ then breaks the line **within** the cell, rather than breaking to a new row.

I hope to understand how to use booktabs, to format hlines and vlines better, which is why it is loaded in this code, but not used (yet!)

I think it needs more work. If anyone wants to take it on, please feel free. I suggest the following:

1. It is too easy to put edits in the wrong places, and mess the whole thing up. Improved data entry to minimise this possibility would be desirable, but I won't bother.
2. Tidy up the code, to make it fit better into the New Interface methods. Again, this works for me, so I will leave it as it is.
3. Make it look better - different font, perhaps, or different horizontal and vertical lines.
4. Convert it into a document class? Perhaps there are too few people interested in using it to make the effort worthwhile. I don't have the skills needed.
5. Enable cross-referencing between different FGS's - a child of one family is a parent of another. It would be useful to include something like "See Table XX". However, I believe that a cross-reference from inside a table is problematical.

I shall keep an eye on this thread, in case anyone decides to comment, but now that I have a working template, I shall concentrate on writing the book, rather than on page layout!

## Edit 14 June 2022

I have added this Family Group Sheet as a project on github:

https://github.com/wortle/fhs_standalone

Thanks again to MS-SPO and L.J.R.for their contributions.

## Edit 19 June 2022

Further on data entry and databases. The design of a database for genealogical data is a thorny issue, which has still not been satisfactorily answered after many years of debate between people with considerably more experience than me. In spite of the many well-documented criticisms of GEDCOM, it still has not been replaced, and is the de-facto standard. Every Genealogy software package seems to use it's own database schema. However, they are all able to export their data in GEDCOM format.

I am sure it would be possible for someone to write a script to parse a GEDCOM file and batch-produce Family History Sheets. Sed, awk, perl? It is also possible to do it in LuaTeX (see question 97822). That is beyond my capabilities. I am not asking anyone to do it: just flagging up possibilities.

Comment: that is imho a rather trivial layout that can be done in many ways, including with the standard tabular and with tikz. I wouldn't choose an input where I have to add commands like \SetCell in every second cell.

Comment: @ UlrikeFischer - It is not at all useful to know what you would NOT do - it would be useful to know what you WOULD do - and how. If you want to use a Family Group Sheet, you do not have to use mine - you can always write your own.

Comment: hm, you asked for suggestions for improvements didn't you? Well my suggestion would be to get rid of all these \SetCell. But if you don't want to do it, then leave it.

Comment: If you run my code, you will see that there are different numbers and arrangements of columns on different rows of the table. If it is possible to do this **without** spanning columns, please tell me how.

Comment: i would probably create two tabulars, or use nested tabulars.

Comment: I had thought of this. The arrangement of columns changes 7 times - I would need 8 tables, which may not line up correctly. Please run the code to see what it produces. Would your 8-table solution result in less coding to achieve this result? Would it be simpler, or more difficult, to do it in tikz? Column 1 is needed in order to provide the sequence numbers of the children in the penultimate part of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet a solution, but already too much to say to put as comments. A few observations, answers and suggestions.

**Strategy**

I suggest as strategy: write first, care about layout later (Q3). Looks like your book project is already quite big. So, if you use the book-class, many of your layout-trouble may already have been addressed. Who knows, perhaps you like the predefined result later?

However, you should make an early decision on the table-tool you use, e.g. by trying out different scenarios, before deciding. There are many table-packages available on ctan (https://www.ctan.org/topic/table), some outdated, some nice new ones. Whatever your choice will be, you probably won’t rewrite it into a different package again. So, spend some time on scenarios and testing different tables, including `tikz` may be.

**Data handling**

Related to your Q1 is this: From a data point of view, you have a typical application for a relational database. I.e. you’d come up with a versatile set of tables and relationships amongst them, which will cope with 99 % of your family data situations.

Next, you’d query for whatever you may want to find out. With some extra work you can use those query results and output them as Latex-source code for further processing, see below.

E.g. some queries could  give you data about husband, wife (both including notes), children. From these you construct your latex code using your databases functionalities (i.e. let it generate the code you posted, couple by couple).

There is no better way to avoid errors (Q1) in huge data sets.

Package `genealogy` talks about and uses a “database”, but a quick view did not ensure me, it’s a relational one. Which means: you probably won’t be able to generate queries, which will impose severe limitations to your project.

In reverse, a separate database could as well query and generate formats you can re-use with the genealogy package. Think of different way to present your query results, “decorated” by some extra code.

**Q4, documentclass**

I suggest not to do it as a beginner. Just inspect some documentclasses with your editor, or read the long implementation documentation in many package manuals and you’ll easily understand, why.

**Cross-references Q5**

The varioref package does a nice job for you (https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/varioref.pdf) . I’ll show you an example, below.

**Book example “Our huge Family”**

Please find some screenshots and code below.

**Practical considerations**

A widely used approach is having a kind of framework .tex file, starting with the documentclass, including all packages needed and so on, an detailing chaptes etc.

In relatively short documents you could write all content here as well. However, navigation can get tough after a while. So a common approach is to move the latex-code, say for a chapters content, into a separate file and `\include` it in the framework. This works quite well.

However, Latex is specialized in typesetting, which is a late step in the process from idea to paper (or pdf). What comes before that  is the process of writing, which comprises research, sketching, trials, changing sequences, reviews, starting from scratch in parts and so on.

There are not many tools out there, which support this process of writing (converting ideas into text without any layout restrictions). Word processors don’t offer these layout-free approaches. The best tool for this purpose you can have is (without any advertisement) called Scrivener (this text was sketched and refined by using it).

Though Scrivener can export to Latex, this export creates complicated code. It’s fairly easy in reverse, to include the few Latex-codes you’d need on the fly while writing. (Compile, copy to your Latex-Tool, compile, and you have a book version).

BTW, the book was also designed with Scrivener AND processed with TexMaker. That’s why I can afford one long .tex file, as I do navigation, restructuring, changing etc. in Scrivener.

How the writing process may look like in Scrivener; kindly regonize the `varioref` used, which is encapsulated in a `\newcommand` called `\tbl` to ease the pain of writing:

[image: writing-process with Scrivener]

Screenshot collage of the rudimentary book, including a `genealogytree` and your table. Links are still rendered by red boxes, but can be made invisible.

[image: Result]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}

% ~~~ referencing tables ~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\tbl[1]{ 
    table \vref{tbl:#1}
}

% ~~~ data to be included in the document properties ~~~
\usepackage[pdftitle={Our huge Family},
pdfauthor={Bill Berry},
pdfkeywords={key1, key2 key 3}]{hyperref}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% ~~~ cmd: makeindex Iridium.idx ~~~

\begin{document}

    \title{Our huge Family} 
    \author{Bill Berry}
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro}

Have a look at the Family Group Tree in \tbl{FGT}.% <<<<< here's a ref

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer eget nulla mollis aliquam urna. Enim egestas augue Phasellus In parturient porttitor nibh Aliquam ut nibh. Vitae ante vel Morbi leo platea Pellentesque sit Sed interdum Quisque. 

Et Curabitur habitant Vivamus a nibh pulvinar et id tempor condimentum. Et metus semper id urna purus est ut eget penatibus risus. Turpis eleifend elit ligula Phasellus.

Dolor lorem semper felis tincidunt et massa eget nulla Morbi ridiculus. At lorem sit ipsum turpis platea pede justo Vestibulum ante lobortis. Dolor Vivamus senectus dui.

Sit justo sem faucibus wisi ligula vel est neque tincidunt elit. Praesent libero augue felis nibh Aenean Curabitur lacus vitae semper Curabitur. Cursus at ac Pellentesque elit id tristique enim.

At ligula vitae Suspendisse vel tempus et Morbi tincidunt Aenean ipsum. Porttitor neque dictumst habitasse In ligula mauris quis wisi quis et. Tempor at gravida sed laoreet interdum velit tempus elit.


\chapter{}

\section{What readers should know}

Dolor lorem semper felis tincidunt et massa eget nulla Morbi ridiculus. At lorem sit ipsum turpis platea pede justo Vestibulum ante lobortis. Dolor Vivamus senectus dui.

Sit justo sem faucibus wisi ligula vel est neque tincidunt elit. Praesent libero augue felis nibh Aenean Curabitur lacus vitae semper Curabitur. Cursus at ac Pellentesque elit id tristique enim.
\section{Other things to say}

Dolor lorem semper felis tincidunt et massa eget nulla Morbi ridiculus. At lorem sit ipsum turpis platea pede justo Vestibulum ante lobortis. Dolor Vivamus senectus dui.

Sit justo sem faucibus wisi ligula vel est neque tincidunt elit. Praesent libero augue felis nibh Aenean Curabitur lacus vitae semper Curabitur. Cursus at ac Pellentesque elit id tristique enim.
\section{Genealogy}

Example from the genealogy package:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree{
parent{
g{first child}
c{second child}
c{third child}
p{father}
p{mother}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\section{Family Group Sheet}\label{tbl:FGT}

\begin{table} 
        \footnotesize
        \caption{Family Group Sheet}
        \begin{tblr}{width=1\linewidth,hspan=minimal,
                colspec={
                |X[c,m,0.3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,0.9cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,1.2cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |X[l,m,3cm,leftsep=1.5pt,rightsep=1.5pt]
                |}}
            
            \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{c}\normalsize \textbf{Husband} & 1-2 & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Bill Berry & 1-4 & 1-5 & \normalsize \textbf{Wife} & \SetCell[c=3]{l} see \vref{intro} &x&x \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Birth} &x& date &  \textbf{Place} & where & \textbf{Birth} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline% <<< column wife has a ref
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Military}  &x& \SetCell[c=3]{} what &x&&  \textbf{Marr.} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Death} & x & date &  \textbf{Place} & where &  \textbf{Death} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Burial} & x & date &  \textbf{Place} & where &  \textbf{Burial} & date &  \textbf{Place} & where \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=2]{l} \textbf{Father} & x & date &  \textbf{Mother} & where &  \textbf{Father} & date &  \textbf{Mother} & where \\ \hline
             \hline
            \SetCell[c=5]{h,l}\SetRow{12ex}\normalsize \textbf{Notes} \footnotesize {\\Write here,  } & 7-2 & 7-3 & 7-4 & 7-5 &  \SetCell[c=4]{h,l} \normalsize \textbf{Notes} \footnotesize {\\Here} & 7-7 & 7-8 & 7-9 \\ \hline
%DO NOT EDIT NEXT LINE          
            \SetCell[c=3]{c}\textbf{Children} & 8-2 & 8-3 & \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Birth} & 8-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{c}\textbf{Marriage} & 8-7 & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Death and Burial} & 8-9 \\ \hline% DO NOT EDIT THIS LINE
            1 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            2 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            3 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            4 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            6 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            7 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            8 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            9 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            10 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} name &x& \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-5 & \SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-7 &\SetCell[c=2]{l} date & 9-9 \\ \hline
            \SetCell[c=9]{l}\textbf{Additional Notes}\footnotesize {\\Write here}  & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
            \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

**P.S.**:  The code is prepared to process `\index{}` entries, but none were set so far.

Comment: Thank you - that is very helpful. I have a main.tex with the essential, but each chapter is a separate document. Every tree and every Family Group Sheet will also be a separate document.

Comment: Second comment - I had tried to insert a line break, but it closed the comment! I will accept this as the best answer. I am impressed that you took the trouble to produce an example yourself, to demonstrate how it could be done. Thank you. I will take your advice, and write first and format later. The database suggestion is also good. However, rather than write my own database schema, I will explore the capabilities of gramps. It may be able to output reports in latex format, which would most likely result in a better result than my first efforts at producing a Family Group Sheet.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will demonstrate how to rewrite a [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) table from "Old Interfaces" to "New Interfaces".

Remark: In `tabularray`, A `Q` column has width, while an `X` column only has coefficient. Therefore it is incorrect to write `X[l,m,3cm]`, and you have to change it to `Q[l,m,3cm]` or `X[l,m,3]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Family Group Sheet}
  \begin{tblr}{hspan=minimal,colsep=1.5pt,
    colspec={|Q[c,m,0.3cm]|Q[l,m,1.2cm]|X[l,m]|Q[l,m]|X[l,m]|Q[l,m]|X[l,m]|Q[l,m]|X[l,m]|},
    %% multicolumn cells:
    cell{1}{1} = {c=2}{l},
    cell{1}{3,7} = {c=3}{l},
    cell{2-6}{1} = {c=2}{l},
    cell{3}{3} = {c=3}{l},
    cell{7,8}{1} = {c=5}{h,l},
    cell{7,8}{6} = {c=4}{h},
    cell{9}{1} = {c=3}{c},
    cell{9}{4,6,8} = {c=2}{c},
    cell{10-X}{even} = {c=2}{l},
    cell{Y,Z}{1} = {c=9}{l},
    %% cell and row styles:
    cell{1-6}{1,4,6,8} = {font=\bfseries},
    cell{1}{1,6} = {font=\normalsize\bfseries},
    row{7} = {font=\normalsize\bfseries,belowsep=0pt},
    row{8} = {ht=9ex,abovesep=0pt},
    row{9} = {font=\bfseries},
    row{Y} = {font=\bfseries,belowsep=0pt},
    row{Z} = {abovesep=0pt},
  }
  \hline
    Husband          & 1-2  & name & 1-4    & 1-5   & Wife     & name & x      & x     \\ \hline
    Birth            & x    & date & Place  & where & Birth    & date & Place  & where \\ \hline
    Military         & x    & what & x      &       & Marr.    & date & Place  & where \\ \hline
    Death            & x    & date & Place  & where & Death    & date & Place  & where \\ \hline
    Burial           & x    & date & Place  & where & Burial   & date & Place  & where \\ \hline
    Father           & x    & date & Mother & where & Father   & date & Mother & where \\ \hline \hline
    Notes            & 7-2  & 7-3  &        &       & Notes    & 7-7  & 7-8    & 7-9   \\
    Write here       & 8-2  & 8-3  & 8-4    &  8-5  & Here     & 8-7  & 8-8    & 8-9   \\ \hline
    Children         & 9-2  & 9-3  & Birth  &  9-5  & Marriage & 9-7  & Death and Burial & 9-9 \\ \hline
     1               & name & x    & date   & 10-5  & date     & 10-7 & date   & 10-9  \\ \hline
     2               & name & x    & date   & 11-5  & date     & 11-7 & date   & 11-9  \\ \hline
     3               & name & x    & date   & 12-5  & date     & 12-7 & date   & 12-9  \\ \hline
     4               & name & x    & date   & 13-5  & date     & 13-7 & date   & 13-9  \\ \hline
     5               & name & x    & date   & 14-5  & date     & 14-7 & date   & 14-9  \\ \hline
     6               & name & x    & date   & 15-5  & date     & 15-7 & date   & 15-9  \\ \hline
     7               & name & x    & date   & 16-5  & date     & 16-7 & date   & 16-9  \\ \hline
     8               & name & x    & date   & 17-5  & date     & 17-7 & date   & 17-9  \\ \hline
     9               & name & x    & date   & 18-5  & date     & 18-7 & date   & 18-9  \\ \hline
    10               & name & x    & date   & 19-5  & date     & 19-7 & date   & 19-9  \\ \hline
    Additional Notes & ~    & ~    & ~      & ~     & ~        & ~    & ~      & ~     \\
    Write here       & ~    & ~    & ~      & ~     & ~        & ~    & ~      & ~     \\ \hline
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is what I wanted, and tried, but couldn't make it work. Much neater than my version.